# Python, determining prime number using recursion

Tags: python, recursion, primes

```
import math

def even(num): 
    if num % 2 != 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True

def is_div(num):
    if num % 2 == 0 or num % 3 == 0 or num %5 == 0 or num % 7 ==0: 
        return True
    else:
        return False

counter = [0]


def is_prime1(num,a):

    if a >= int(math.sqrt(num)):
        return True
    else:
        if num % a == 0:
            return False
        else:
            return is_prime1(num,a+2)


def is_prime(num,a):
counter[0] += 1

    if a >= int(math.sqrt(num)):
        return True
    else:
        if is_prime1(a,3):
            if num % a == 0:
                return False
            else:
                return is_prime(num,a+2)
        else:
            return is_prime(num,a+2)


def det():
    a = 3
    num = int(input("Enter the number? "))

    if num == 2 or num == 3 or num == 5 or num == 7:
        print(num, "is prime")
    elif even(num):
        print(num, "is not prime")
    elif is_div(num):
        print(num, "is not prime")
    elif is_prime(num,a):
        print(num, "is prime")
    else:
        print(num, "is not prime")

det()
print(counter[0])
```

I have started to learn python recently and came across recursion last week.

I have written a program to determine if a number is prime or not using recursion. It works for values in range of 3 million, for bigger values it exceeds the recursion depth.

Is there a way I can improve this program so as to work for bigger values without increasing the recursion depth?

Comment: The simplest way is to not use recursion for this - it's not needed and inefficient in Python.

Comment: yes, there's a way to increase the limit: you could try making `num` global so it's not used in the arguments. but of course, there are better ways of doing this, like sieve of Erathosthenes.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre but that would convert a program based on a bad design choice (using recursion to check prime)  to a program based on the same bad design choice but with bad coding ideas (using globals in a function that should be side-effect free to be called recursively, i.e. getting the worst of imperative and functional programming). And the only benefit would be that it runs a few depths deeper. I strongly recommend **not** following the path of globals. In fact, I've been writing python for 8 years now, and I had to use `global` maybe twice, and I'm happy about that.

Comment: Faraz, while it's important to *understand* recursion, it's a pattern that you'll not find in Python usage, typically, because recursion for non-functional languages (without *tail recursion*, if you want to google something) is simply a very bad idea, due to the way computers actually work.

Comment: @MarcusMüller beat you by 1 year :). Using python since 2008 and `globals` suck and only lead to issues. My comment just stated that it pushes the limit further. Period. But don't do it at home.

Comment: Thank you guys for the help, I will try writing this code without recursion.